# my posts does not route to their detail pages

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to make an blog application with laravel.
my problem is that i have listed my posts in allnews.blade.php view and i described texts as routeable to detail pages of post but it doesn't work

**allnews.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($posts as $post) // this is allnews.blade.php view
        <li>
            <div class="media wow fadeInDown">
               <a href="{{$post->slug}}" class="container"> <img width="100%" height="auto" alt="" 
               src="/storage/{{ $post->image}}"> </a>
              <div class="media-body"> <h3 src="" class="catg_title">{{$post->title}}</h3> </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        @endforeach
```

but when i try to go to my post detail(***by using href $post->slug*** ) i'm having issues with "404 page not found" problem. for my logic all things look perfect. but i cant route.

here is my **PostController.php**

```
 public function DetailofPost($id)
 {
   $PostDetails  = Post::where('slug' , $id)->first();
   return view('PostDetail', compact ('PostDetails'));
 }
```

here is my **PostDetail.blade.php** view

```
         @foreach($PostDetails as $PostDetail)
    
        <h1>{{PostDetail->title}}</h1>
        <div class="single_page_content"> <img class="img-center" src="/storage/{{ $PostDetail->image}}" alt="">
          <blockquote> {{PostDetail->body}}</blockquote>
         @endforeach
```

and here is my routing page  a.k.a **web.php**

```
  Route::get('/', function () {
 return view('welcome');
                             });
 Route::get("/tumhaberler" , 'PostController@ListAll');

 Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
 Voyager::routes();
                                                 });
 Route::get('/{slug}', 'PostController@DetailofPost');
```

Comment: what URL/route returns this `allnews.blade.php` view? you should avoid relative URLs, this is why we have URL helpers ... this seems like an issue of not knowing how relative URLs work with the current base URL

Answer (score 1):

Your `href` should contain a full url, not just your `$post->slug`.

Change the `href` to `url("/{$post->slug}")`, assuming the url you want is something like `http://yoursite.com/title-of-my-post`

See docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/urls#introduction

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the slug into the URL:

```
<a href="{{$post->slug}}"
```

but trying to find the post in your controller using ID:

```
public function DetailofPost($id)
```

If you want to always use the slug as the identifier, you need to tell Laravel this by changing your route to:

```
Route::get('/{post:slug}', 'PostController@DetailofPost');
```

and then change your controller function to automatically load the post with that slug:

```
public function DetailofPost(App\Post $post)
```

And then in the controller, you won't need to set `$PostDetails` as you'll have the variable `$post`.

This is called [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding).

Comment: since they are not using model binding, this is not the issue

Answer (score -1):

Thank you everyone i solved the problem.

```
     @foreach($PostDetails as $PostDetail) //this is my detail page
     <h1>{{PostDetail->title}}</h1>
    <div class="single_page_content"> <img class="img-center" src="/storage/{{ 
     $PostDetail->image}}" alt="">
     <blockquote> {{PostDetail->body}}</blockquote>
     @endforeach
```

my logic was wrong. in my controller i set it like that my controller fetch the id of post from database than fullfill them on detail page by id related database columns like 'slug' or 'title'
as you guys see there is no need use @foreach  and here is my updated code from PostDetail.blade.php

```
       <div class="single_page">
        <h1>{{$PostDetails->title}}</h1>
        <div class="single_page_content"> <img class="img-center" src="/storage/{{ 
        $PostDetails->image}}" alt=""> </div>
        <a>  {{$PostDetails->body}} </a>
```